# WPF x:Reference thow Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am developing an application in WPF and from some reason Visual studio display in error window this exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

When I was building application this errors are still visible, but I application works correct

this is a my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox Name="cbPersonType" Content="Person Type" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPersonTypeVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid Name="dgPersons">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Person Type"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Source={x:Reference Name=cbPersonType}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                        />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

this exception is on DataGridTextColumn.
Does some one know why and what is this error?

Comment: The XAML editor is buggy. Sometimes it shows error, underlines correct lines of code for no reason. You can try exiting VS and opening it again. I accept to live with that, it's a bit annoying but at least much better than Notepad or even Notepad++

Comment: I tried off and on again studio, but without result. But I'm sure you're right, it's much better than to write something exotic like Notepad

Answer (score 2):

This is just a theory from my part trying to explain the errormessage.

Right now I'm struggling with a similar case. However, I have my checkbox in a contextmenu displaying the columns in a datagrid. The user can check the columns he/she wants to see in the datagrid.

Problem is the checkboxes seem not to be initlized until the user actually right-click to open the contextmenu. Until then the datagrid just shows empty rows with no columns at all.

It seems the x:Reference does not kick in until the checkboxes are loaded in the contextmenu.

A simplified XAML of the contextmenu and datagrid is below.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Columnsetup">
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkHeadOrderNo" Content="Ordernumber" IsChecked="{Binding columnVisibilityHeadOrderNo}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderNo}" Header="Ordernumber" 
                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference chkHeadOrderNo}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource convertVisibility}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to replace
`Source={x:Reference Name=cbPersonType}` with `ElementName=cbPersonType`. This works fine both in design and runtime modes

Comment: This doesn't work if your binding source is outside the scope of your datagrid.  Using x:Reference is required in this case.